# How to aggregate over several alternative terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents which may have several, well defined, attributes I want to aggregate over:

```
{
  name: "john",
  age: "51"
},
{
  name: "mary",
  years_since_born: "34"
},
{
  name: "mike",
  age: "34"
},
```

The fields `age` and `years_since_born` mean the same thing, but have a different name.

**I would like to aggregate the documents by `age` OR `years_since_born`. Is that possible?**

I tried to push a [`bool` condition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in my `terms` but it apparently only accepts strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [script in your `terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script), like this:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ages": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "params._source.age != null ? params._source.age : params._source.years_since_born"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: however, the performance can get bad depending on your document count. It'd be better if all documents use the same field.